# Best approach to auto create profile object upon user creation in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I was wondering what would be the best way to auto create and assign a related Profile object to a user upon creation in django.

Any Ideas or Links to check out?

Comment: use django signals

Comment: There is a [good example in the official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  "What is the best way?" is simply a wrapper around "give me code/design to solve this problem" -- which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
Asking for off-site "ideas or links" is specifically off-topic here.

Comment: I know all the ways to achieve it, I am just not sure about the best way that's all. Thanks.

Comment: "I know all the ways to achieve it, I am just not sure about the best way that's all"—then you're in the wrong place. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions that are primarily opinion-based are explicitly _off-topic_.

Answer (score 3):

the best approach is to use `signals`

in `models.py`

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
        primary_key=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        help_text=_('User (Required).'),
    )

[..]
```

create a separated `signals.py` file

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save

from .models import User, Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='user.create_user_profile')
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='user.save_user_profile')
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

then register `signals` in `apps.py` (since we used `@receiver` decorator)

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.accounts'
    verbose_name = _('Accounts and Profiles')

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

have a look at this tutorial https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Comment: Why are we importing pre_save if we're not going to use it?

Comment: Also that didn't seem to work for me for some reason, It only works if I put the logic in the models file and use the post_save.connect method!!

Comment: in fact i copy pasted a code from my project , i already removed bunch of things, in your case you don't need it , just remove it

Comment: you're right, there 2 methods to register signals via `@receiver` decorator and via `post_save.connect(save_profile, sender=User)` just refer to the tuto and the official docs and choose which is easy to you